# After pacman update, pacsearch is no longer installed

Tags: package-management, pacman

I updated Arch Linux and now pacsearch is gone.

I know you can `pacman -Ss`, but I really liked how cool pacsearch was.

How can I get pacsearch back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the [release of pacman 5.1.0](https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/NEWS#n10), many of those supporting applications have been split out into pacman-contrib:

```
pacman -Fs pacsearch
community/pacman-contrib 1.0.0-2
    usr/bin/pacsearch


pacman -Ql pacman-contrib | awk -F/ '/bin/ {print $4}'

checkupdates
paccache
pacdiff
paclist
paclog-pkglist
pacscripts
pacsearch
pacsort
pactree
rankmirrors
updpkgsums
```